# Run tasks sequentially

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have five windows services. I run the services sequentially.

```
if(a_Condition)
{ 
     services[0] = new Processing_0();
// blah blah
}
if(b_Condition)
{
    service[1] = new Processing_1();
// blah blah
}
if(c_Condition)
{
    service[2] = new Processing_2();
// blah blah
}
if(d_Condition)
{
    service[3] = new Processing_3();
// blah blah
}
if(e_Condition)
{
    service[4] = new Processing_4();
// blah blah
}
```

For some reason, I want to use task, the code is:

```
Task.StartNew(() => {
if (a_Condition) { var x = new Processing_0(); ... }
})
.ContinueWith(() => {
if (b_Condition) { var x = new Processing_1(); ... }
})
.ContinueWith(() => {
if (c_Condition) { var x = new Processing_2(); ... }
}) 
.ContinueWith(() => {
if (d_Condition) { var x = new Processing_3(); ... }
})
.ContinueWith(() => {
if (e_Condition) { var x = new Processing_4(); ... }
});
```

Is that okay?

Comment: Are you fine with the various conditions (`a_Condition` and so on) being evaluated in a deferred way (just before each individual task starts) or do you want them evaluated eagerly before _any_ of the tasks start?

Comment: All the condition values come from app.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fine!

Check out MSDN's article on Continuations at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks